# println! outside of loop is an unreachable statement, how to use a println in a "reachable" way

Tags: rust

How can I print the frequencies `HashSet` after the loop terminates? Problem seems to be there is no guarantee the loop terminates.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let f = fs::read_to_string("input.txt").expect("Unable to open file");

    let mut total = 0;
    let mut frequencies = HashSet::new();
    frequencies.insert(0);

    loop {
        for line in f.lines() {
            let line_trimmed = line.trim();
            let something = line_trimmed.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
            total += something;
            // println!("{:?}",total);

            if frequencies.contains(&total) {
                println!("duplicated found {:?}", total);
                return;
            }
            frequencies.insert(total);
        }
    }
    println!("duplicated found {:?}", frequencies);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`println!("duplicated found {:?}", frequencies);` is unreachable because, when you are calling `return`, you are returning out of the `main` function.

Change loop to a while, and set a variable to exit the while loop.

```
let mut duplicated_found = false;
while !duplicated_found {
    for line in f.lines() {

        let line_trimmed = line.trim();
        let something = line_trimmed.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        total += something;
        // println!("{:?}",total);

        if frequencies.contains(&total) {
            println!("duplicated found {:?}", total);
            duplicated_found = true;
            break; // This breaks out of the for loop
        }
        frequencies.insert(total);
    }
}
println!("duplicated found {:?}", frequencies);
```

OR you can use labels to specify which loop you want to break out of:

```
'outer: loop {
    for line in f.lines() {

        let line_trimmed = line.trim();
        let something = line_trimmed.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        total += something;
        // println!("{:?}",total);

        if frequencies.contains(&total) {
            println!("duplicated found {:?}", total);
            break 'outer; // This breaks out of the outer loop
        }
        frequencies.insert(total);
    }
}
println!("duplicated found {:?}", frequencies);
```

Comment: The named label seems like a much more obvious way to break from the outer loop. With a variable, it needs more brain power to know why that variable is here, what it does, and when it's used.